# Check my answer - radius and domain of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, summation

We want to determine the radius and domain of convergence of the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{2n-1}{3n+2})^n(x+2)^n$

I just want to verify my solution and method.

We know that the sum definitely converges if $\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_n}^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is less than $1$. if it is equal exactly the one, then the test is inconclusive and we are going to have to take care of that case, and if it's greater than $1$ that it diverges.

$\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_n}^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n-1}{3n+2}(x+2)=(x+2) \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2n-1}{3n+2}=(x+2)\frac{2}{3}=\frac{2}{3}x+\frac{4}{3}$

We want to know $D=\{x, s.t:  |\frac{2}{3}x+\frac{4}{3}|<1\}$

$-1 < \frac{2}{3}x+\frac{4}{3} < 1$ implies $-\frac{7}{3}< \frac{2}{3}x < -\frac{1}{3}$ and that's equivalent to $-\frac{21}{6} < x <-\frac{1}{2}$

So $D=\{ x \in (-\frac{21}{6},-\frac{1}{2})\}$, and the length of the interval $D$ is $3$, so the radius of convergence is half that, or $\frac{3}{2}$.

Now we just need to figure out if the sum converges for $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $x=-\frac{21}{6}$

I haven't done that yet, but so far is the result correct?

Edit: for $x=-\frac{1}{2}$:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{6n-3}{6n+4})^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{6n+4-7}{6n+4})^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{-7}{6n+4})^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}[(1+\frac{-7}{6n+4})^{\frac{6n+4}{-7}}]^{\frac{-7n}{6n+4}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{\frac{-7n}{6n+4}}=e^{-\frac{7}{6}}\neq 0$$

So the sum diverges for $x=-\frac{1}{2}$. since $a_n$ does not approach zero.

Comment: $\frac{7}{2}=\frac{21}{6}$

Comment: However, the length of $\bigl(-\frac{7}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\bigr)$ is $3$, not $4$.

Comment: that's true. that's a miscalculation. it's late :)

Comment: @OriaGruber: It happens alot!

Comment: any comments about the limit calculation?

Comment: @OriaGruber:  It is correct!

Comment: You're right that at $x=-\frac12$ (indeed, also at $x=-\frac72$) the summand doesn't even tend to $0$, and so the sum can't converge there.